# I can't send request more than 1200 bytes from Telnet with Java {Closed}

Tags: java, telnet

I write simple telnet application with java, this application send request (xml) and read response. But when I send request (from java) more than 1200 bytes then I get HTTP 500. If I send this command from command line I get HTTP 200 (Ok). Is there max size limit  in java?

My Code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Socket pingSocket = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            pingSocket = new Socket("host", 4380);
            out = new PrintWriter(pingSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pingSocket.getInputStream()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        String newLine = "\n";
        String header = "POST /path HTTP/1.1" + newLine
                + "Host: host:4380" + newLine
                + "Authorization: Basic cuyasdyq123ha123" + newLine
                + "Connection: close" + newLine
                + "SOAPAction: \"\"" + newLine
                + "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" + newLine
                + "Content-Length: 2000" + newLine;

        String request = "my xml data here";

        System.out.println(header + request);

        out.println(header);
        out.println(request);

        System.out.println(in.readLine());
        System.out.println();

        while (in.read() != -1) {
            System.out.print((char) in.read());
        }

        out.close();
        in.close();
        pingSocket.close();
    }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: When you get a HTTP 500, check your *server* logs to see what's going on there.

Comment: @Manish I get this error:
Unable to create StAX reader or writer

Comment: HTTP 500 Error. I changed it value to (request2.length() + 400)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an encoding issue.  I don't know what encoding you're getting from your command line.  Could well be cp-1252 if you're using windows.  So your 1200 characters probably work out to 1200 bytes, which fits within the 2000 Content-Length that you've specified.

But in Java, every character is represented as two bytes.  So your 1200 characters are turning into 2400 bytes; but the Content-Length: 2000 in the header is making your content cut off prematurely.

Comment: I test it write 2400 (then 3000, ....) but again http 500.  In command line I write "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8". I think it is not content length problem.

Comment: So are you saying that the limit still appears to be 1200 characters (or thereabouts) even with Content-Length 3000?  So the limit is independent of the setting of Content-Length?  Are you sure?  Is it possible that the 1200th character of your input is something that the StAX parser doesn't understand?  Does the server give you any more information than the one line that you've quoted?

Comment: If content length invalid, then why I can send this command from command line? Server does not give any information, the server response is Unable to create StAX reader or writer.

Comment: As I explained, the content length counts bytes, and in Java, when you write `out.println`, you output two bytes for each character; but the telnet application that you're using from the command line is most likely only sending one byte for each character.

Comment: not you are not right. It is the problem of network. (Cisco, MTU size)